# Dragging textbox in C# winforms application stuttering

Tags: c#, winforms, draggable

I have a winforms app that allows a user to drag a textbox around in a panel.

When the click, I set a boolean flag "moveMode" and then I set the location to be that of the mouse as they drag.

The problem is it stutters and isn't smooth.The picture below is one textbox object being dragged 
[image]

I think it might be the repaint isn't fast enough for dragging? Is there a way to increase this repaint rate?

Here is my code for the mouseMove Event for the textbox:

```
    void textBox1_mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggingTxtBox && moveMode)
        {
            Point newLocation = new Point();
            newLocation.X = e.Location.X - dragOffset.X;
            newLocation.Y = e.Location.Y - dragOffset.Y;
            txtBox.Location = newLocation;
            dragOffset = e.Location;
            dragOffset.X -= txtBox.Location.X;
            dragOffset.Y -= txtBox.Location.Y;

            txtBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            this.Refresh();
            txtBox.Refresh();
        }

            Point newPos = new Point();
            newPos.X = e.X + offset.X;
            newPos.Y = e.Y + offset.Y;}
```

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384381/control-that-allows-dragging-of-form)  may this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384381/control-that-allows-dragging-of-form)

```
Point dragOffset;

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        dragOffset = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        var formLocation = FindForm().Location;
        dragOffset.X -= formLocation.X;
        dragOffset.Y -= formLocation.Y;
    }
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        Point newLocation = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        newLocation.X -= dragOffset.X;
        newLocation.Y -= dragOffset.Y;
        FindForm().Location = newLocation;
    }
}
```